# why does jpeg_decompress_create crash without error message?

Tags: c, crash, exit, libjpeg, compression

I've a problem with just this sample of code :

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
```

My program exits on `jpeg_create_decompress` without error message. Any one have an idea ?

Comment: You might find it helpful to run your program through a debugger such as gdb.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't because i'm using libjpeg on Android with JNI NDK on Eclipse and the debugger fails to launch. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution !

On Android, there is already a libjpeg.so installed and it appears it is loaded in priority. This one seems to be configured differently.
So, you have to rename your shared library libjpeg into a different name.

For me, i renamed from libjpeg.so to libmyjpeg.so.

Answer (score 1):

You should have been doing:

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr); // <<-- cinfo here!
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, it was effectively cinfo.

Comment: But the problem is still here.